# Step data in BDD using python and differencess between Scenario Outline

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

How step data works in behave?e.g I have this part of code

```
Scenario: some scenario
  Given a set of specific users
     | name      | department  |
     | jon       | Beer Cans   |
     | adda      | Silly Walks |
     | Two-Lumps | Silly Walks |
 When we count the number of people in each department
 Then we will find two people in "Silly Walks"
  But we will find one person in "Beer Cans"
```

and implementation

```
@given('a set of specific users')
def step_impl(context):
    for row in context.table:
        model.add_user(name=row['name'], department=row['department'])
```

which is not working for me.

what that `@given` step do? I would be grateful for more examples of use steps and features

---

Ok so does this code under doing the same as code with outline scenario?

```
Scenario: Update user detail
    Given I login to update user details
    When I update following user detail "<item_name>" and "<item_detail>"
      | item_name | item_detail           |
      | address   | Dragon street  Brazil |
      | contact   | 001 85208520 00       |
      | name      | Uncle scrooge         |
      | surname   | Mcduck                |
    Then User detail update should be successful

@when(u'I update following user detail "{item_name}" and "{item_detail}"')
def step_impl(context, item_name, item_detail):
    print('Following user details are being updated')
    for row in context.table:
        context.temp_item_name = row['item_name']
        context.temp_item_detail = row['item_detail']
        print('======  ' + context.temp_item_name + '  ' + context.temp_item_detail)


Scenario Outline: Update user detail
    Given I login to update user details
    When I update following user detail "<item_name>" and "<item_detail>"
    Then User detail update should be successful

  Examples: 
      | item_name | item_detail           |
      | address   | Dragon street  Brazil |
      | contact   | 001 85208520 00       |
      | name      | Uncle scrooge         |
      | surname   | Mcduck                |
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the error and stack trace? Or is it just not behaving correctly, and if so how do you expect it to behave and please include more info on how it is currently behaving.

Comment: add_user cannot find reference error

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is. You have two different sets of code. You say you are getting an error. Which set of code is wrong? What's the error? What line of code is triggering the error? Please update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://behave.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial06.html
The Github repository also contains the executable code. Check out the Git repository and run it.